# How to make/duplicate a NEC Infrared Transmission Protocol

Tags: infrared

what i am trying to achieve to be able to duplicate/recreate the infrared signal of my remote control using my arduino.

The arduino has a already a library for this, unfortunately it doesn't seem to support the board that i am going to use the arduino mkr1000. The library has a recieve that makes me able to see the data, but the function for transmitting it back is not working.

So this makes me resort to creating a function for sending myself. I know that the remote i am using uses and NEC infrared transmission protocol. So i looked at its [specs](https://techdocs.altium.com/display/FPGA/NEC+Infrared+Transmission+Protocol).

according to it:

- a 9ms leading pulse burst (16 times the pulse burst length used for a logical data bit)
- a 4.5ms space
- the 8-bit address for the receiving device
- the 8-bit logical inverse of the address
- the 8-bit command
- the 8-bit logical inverse of the command
- a final 562.5µs pulse burst to signify the end of message transmission.

What i dont understand is, what is this address and command.

unfortunaly i do not have an oscilloscope inorder to probe my remote to confirm some hypothesis. What i have though is the output of the serial monitor the arduino upon recieving the signal.

```
Encoding  : NEC
Code      : 2FD807F (32 bits)
Timing[67]: 
    +9200, -4500     + 600, - 550     + 600, - 550     + 600, - 550
    + 600, - 550     + 550, - 600     + 550, - 550     + 600, -1700
    + 600, - 550     + 600, -1700     + 550, -1700     + 600, -1700
    + 600, -1700     + 550, -1700     + 600, -1700     + 550, - 600
    + 550, -1700     + 600, -1700     + 550, - 550     + 600, - 550
    + 600, - 550     + 600, - 550     + 600, - 550     + 550, - 600
    + 550, - 550     + 600, - 550     + 600, -1700     + 600, -1700
    + 550, -1700     + 600, -1700     + 600, -1700     + 550, -1700
    + 600, -1700     + 600

unsigned int  rawData[67] = {9200,4500, 600,550, 600,550, 600,550, 600,550, 550,600, 550,550, 600,1700, 600,550, 600,1700, 550,1700, 600,1700, 600,1700, 550,1700, 600,1700, 550,600, 550,1700, 600,1700, 550,550, 600,550, 600,550, 600,550, 600,550, 550,600, 550,550, 600,550, 600,1700, 600,1700, 550,1700, 600,1700, 600,1700, 550,1700, 600,1700, 600};  // NEC 2FD807F
unsigned int  data = 0x2FD807F;
```

From the output can we point out which is the address and which is the command? so that i will be able to create a code for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the sample capture you have the data right there => 0x02FD807F. The address is 0x02. The logical inverse of the address is the 0xFD. The command is the 0x80. And the logical inverse of the command is the 0x7F value.

Comment: A follow up question. in the specification it is saying "pulse burst" does this have to be followed? can i  just turn the led on for 9us or does it have to be bursted at 38khz

Comment: @Jack - Bursted at 38kHz.

Comment: Now that will add some challenges in the coding. Thank you very much i will try to tackle the challenge now.

Comment: I deleted my first comment because it contains error that might confuse someone else, I will say my thank you again here , I was not critical enough to notice that there are inverse pair in the data.

Comment: Just to let you know i finished the code and made it work ! Thank you very much

Comment: @Jack - Really glad it worked out for you.

Comment: Hello , as i was testing a different remote this one does not seem to follow the convention. The library did still state that it is NEC encoding, the data is 0x90A0060A.  as you may see if we break it down  0x90 is not the inverse of 0xA0 so does 0x06 nad 0x0A. any thoughts?

Comment: No idea at all @Jack.